# Kernel panic immediately on a fresh debian SD card

Tags: debian, wireless

My Pi was working for a while while I tried to set up a wifi dongle, I started getting kernel panics. I thought I might have messed something up so put in a fresh SD card with a fresh Debian image. I get a kernel panic at the login prompt now (takes about 40 seconds to happen).

Is this a hardware problem?  Should I ask for an exchange?

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: Does it do that consistently? I had kernel panics on one boot, and following a power cycle I never saw it happen again. I think it may have had something to do with the config I'd set up and what peripherals I had attached at the time... I would play with it a little more before calling it bad hardware - though that's possible too.

Comment: Have you since removed the wifi dongle? Have you tried another sd card? If yes to both of these, i would ask for an exchange.

Comment: What power supply are you using?

Comment: From @Ejoso: Does it do that consistently? I had kernel panics on one boot, and following a power cycle I never saw it happen again. I think it may have had something to do with the config I'd set up and what peripherals I had attached at the time... I would play with it a little more before calling it bad hardware - though that's possible too.

Comment: Did you check the sha1sum of your downloaded image?

Comment: I left the dongle completely out of the equation while trying to test the Pi.
Yes, I checked the checksum.
I'm powering it with a 4-AA-battery -> USB converter.
I actually haven't used another SD card.  I'll try that, then ask for an exchange if that fails.

Comment: .. Try not using a real usb power supply. You might be undervolting the RPI with those batteries.

Comment: Cable may also be the problem. If the resistance is too high (usually with ultra-thin cables), the voltage will drop. This is a serious consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of the latest raspbian and not using a battery-pack as a power supply meant no kernel panic.  This answer is only to point out that power issues *do* lead to kernel panics.

Answer (score 5):

Wifi dongle is most likely no supported. It takes too much power from the USB port.

- [An official list of working and not working ahrdware](http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals#USB_WiFi_Adapters)
- [Supported and tested dongles by another user](http://raspberrywifi.com/)

Remember that USB hubs, keyboards and many other USB peripherals are also in the list and most of them will not work. (it seems any USB mouse works.. yay! but no on screen keyboard in any X.. doh)

I got the very same messages when I first booted squeeze with a generic 8139usb g/b and I got kernel panics and all sorts of garbage. Took it out and works fine . Also when you try and plug it in after it boots.. it crashed to OS in similar fashion.